# MongoDB: nested search in list of DBREFs

Tags: mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I'm in front of a Mongo DB that uses lists of nested `DBREF`s. (Yes, i know that's a very strange way to use Mongo, and beside this,  it would be better not to use the `@DBREF`)

We have collections of readers, books and authors.

The reader looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("12345"),
    "age" : 37,
    "books" : [ 
        {
            "$ref" : "book",
            "$id" : "123"
        }, 
        {
            "$ref" : "book",
            "$id" : "456"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `$ref` contains the collection name, the `$id` the id of the book.

Obviously, the books look the same way; instead of a list of books DBREFs, they have a list of authors DBREFs.

Two questions:

1. Is there a way to list the readers with books of author1 in their list?
2. How can I list the readers that have only books of authors less than 40 years?

Trying to solve this with Java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query based on database references with the Java driver, use the class [DBRef](https://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBRef.html?_ga=1.196115500.1637474311.1442494082).

#### 1. Is there a way to list the readers with books of author1 in their list?

Yes. Get all book IDs of `author1` with a separate query and then find all readers that have a book reference [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/in/) your list of book IDs.

#### 2. How can I list the readers that have only books of authors less than 40 years?

This time, you'll need three queries:

1. Find the IDs of all authors younger than 40
2. Find all books that have an author with ID [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/in/) your list from step 1.
3. Find all readers that have a book with ID [**`$in`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/query/in/) your list from step 2.

This may be quite heavy, but that's what you get for storing data in a normalized way in a database that does not support joins. Another approach would be to restructure your data in a way that will simplify your queries.